# Jquery code with .hide() function doesn't works in Django template

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am tying to use jQuery in my Django template. When I click my `#edit-website-btn` button nothing happens. Inside the console there aren't any errors. What is wrong?

```
<!-- in <head> -->
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#edit-website-btn').click(function () {
            $('#account-website').hide();
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- in <body> -->
{% for account in accounts %}
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="account-website">{{ account.website }}</div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="edit-website-btn">
        Edit
      </button>
      <form id="website-form" class="hidden">
        <input type="text" id="new-website" name="new-website">
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do you have multiple elements in the DOM which have the same `id`? If so, use classes. Are the elements dynamically appended? If so you'll need to use a delegated event handler

Comment: try placing console.log inside click function, and try checking same things suggested by Rory Mccrossan

Comment: @Rory McCrossan yes I have. Here is my full page code https://pastebin.com/vumQ0hRP

Comment: That's your issue then, `id` attributes have to be unique within the DOM. Use classes instead.

Comment: try with the onclick on the button not the div

Comment: @Rory McCrossan but if I do not need to hide all elements from my loop? I need to hide just one.

Comment: so put an unique id, id are made to be unique. Or just look at his css path

Comment: @Bestasttung how can I put unique id if I create elements in loop?

Comment: How is this a django question actually ?

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers because I use it inside django template and there may be some differences

Comment: @kolas you'd have the very same problem using PHP or Rails or any templating system. This is only an HTML / javascript issue and has nothing to do with Django itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because your Django loop which outputs the HTML is creating multiple elements with the same `id`, which is invalid. You can fix this by using common classes instead, then using DOM traversal in jQuery to relate the elements when the button is clicked. Try this:

```
<td>
  <div class="account-website">{{ account.website }}</div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary edit-website-btn">
    Edit
  </button>
  <form id="website-form" class="hidden">
    <input type="text" class="new-website" name="new-website">
  </form>
</td>
```

```js
$(function () {
  $('.edit-website-btn').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.account-website').hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you, but your example does not works =(. May be is there any best practice how to soleve my issue? When I created elements trow the loop? I need when I click the button there will hide only one element, not all.

Comment: This does follow best practice. Please give more information about what happens when you run this code, as it does work: http://jsfiddle.net/d93c1zLm/

Comment: here is full code https://pastebin.com/8Fwwdyeg, please say me what is wrong? When I click at the button still nothing happens.

Comment: That code looks fine. Try adding `console.log('click')` within the click handler and check if it appears in the console. Are you sure these elements aren't being added to the DOM after it loads?

Comment: there is no output from the console

Comment: Try a delegated handler: `$(document).on('click', '.edit-website-btn', function() {...`